# Can I set my core file location without being root?

Tags: linux, proc, non-root-user, core-dump

It seems strange that I need to be root in order to say "place cores in my current directory" (via `cat whatever /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern`). Isn't there any user-specific override for this?

Answer (score 1):

On my node:

```
 ll /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  1 21:32 /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

It is only writable by root.

Also

```
chmod 666 /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern 
chmod: changing permissions of `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern': Operation not permitted
```

So I think you may not be able to override it.

Comment: Winston I was hoping there was a workaround not involving you  having to write there directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here (Fedora 23) it is hooked up to pipe the core file to report crashes automatically via abrt. Mangle at your own risk.